# get some data from json data by php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json data which I get from fortigate firewall using api, the data is json data, I want to go through this data and get some info from it. 
this is the data which I get

```
array(10) {
 ["http_method"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["results"]=>
   array(2) {
[0]=>
array(14) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "auth_logon"
  ["username"]=>
  string(5) "mihai"
  ["usergroup"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "mihai"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["duration"]=>
  string(11) "123 seconds"
  ["duration_secs"]=>
  int(123)
  ["auth_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["ipaddr"]=>
  string(10) "10.10.80.1"
  ["src_type"]=>
  string(3) "ip4"
  ["expiry"]=>
  string(13) "28799 seconds"
  ["expiry_secs"]=>
  int(28799)
  ["traffic_vol"]=>
  string(12) "323318 bytes"
  ["traffic_vol_bytes"]=>
  int(323318)
  ["method"]=>
  string(8) "Firewall"
}
[1]=>
array(14) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "auth_logon"
  ["username"]=>
  string(9) "testicafe"
  ["usergroup"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "testicafe"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["duration"]=>
  string(11) "182 seconds"
  ["duration_secs"]=>
  int(182)
  ["auth_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["ipaddr"]=>
  string(10) "10.10.80.2"
  ["src_type"]=>
  string(3) "ip4"
  ["expiry"]=>
  string(13) "28799 seconds"
  ["expiry_secs"]=>
  int(28799)
  ["traffic_vol"]=>
  string(12) "274990 bytes"
  ["traffic_vol_bytes"]=>
  int(274990)
  ["method"]=>
  string(8) "Firewall"
}
  }
 ["vdom"]=>
  string(4) "root"
  ["path"]=>
  string(4) "user"
   ["name"]=>
   string(8) "firewall"
 ["action"]=>
 string(6) "select"
 ["status"]=>
 string(7) "success"
 ["serial"]=>
 string(16) "FG201E4Q17902047"
 ["version"]=>
 string(6) "v5.6.9"
 ["build"]=>
int(1673)
}
```

I want to go through this data and retrieve some info like username ,ipaddr and traffic_vol_bytes  ,what should I do to get it

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any code to share? Maybe looked at [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? Very broad question. Perhaps you want to put this structured data into something like a database to start with?

Comment: yes I tried a lot but I get Undefined offset I tried with $phpArray[0]['username']; I get the info but when I put the code inside for loop I get offset error 
or($i=0;$i<sizeof($phpArray);$i++)echo $phpArray[$i]['username'];

Comment: If you share that code we could likely tell you what you are doing wrong. Really how this site works. We want to help you, not necessarily do all the work for you. Try a `foreach` and sprinkle in `var_dump`'s until you really understand the structure of the array you are iterating on.

Comment: can you add your json data. Because this give an issue while fetching  a data.

Comment: You are missing the results part. Access it like this: $phpArray['results'][0]['username']; cheers!

Comment: @jaumebalust are you able to access above response in php code to get username.